# Call javascript function on all events on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a framework and I should be able to capture all the user events on a page like text change, button click, drop down selected, iframe loaded, page loaded.

I have all the code to capture the event, but that would be called only when we call that function onchange or onclick events.

```
@Html.TextBox("tLoanNo",null, new { @onchange = "onChangeOfValue(this);" })
<button id="Search" class="tracker" onclick="onChangeOfValue(this);">Search</button>
```

Is there a way to call my function without adding extra code? I have tried something like this:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
  var oldValue = $(this).attr("defaultValue");
  var newValue = $(this).val();
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if(oldValue != newValue) {
    LogEvents(name + " Text Changed", ' from :' + oldValue + ' To :' + newValue,@((int)TrackerHitTypeLID.Event),@((int)TrackerCategoryLID.Text),232);
  }
});
```

However it does not get called all times.

Comment: As an aside, isn't it a little redundant to build a framework to detect user events by using jQuery, which is itself a framework that can detect user events...?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the user events"?

Comment: Almost everything you do on a website could be a potential "event", if you end up capturing all those events, it would mean disaster & will hamper your application/browser performance for good. Your framework would then be **counter-productive**.

Comment: we would like to capture all user events like textbox onchange event, button onclick event, dropdown onselection.

Comment: if there are any existing tools, please advice

Comment: We are creating  framework on our own.

Comment: There are some tools like NewRelic, which will let you capture all the user actions